# Question on finding pushout of the following diagram.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subseteq X.$ What will be the pushout of the following diagram?
>
> \begin{array}{}  A   \longrightarrow *\\ \big\downarrow {\iota}\\  X \end{array}

By definition the pushout of this diagram is $(X \coprod \{*\})/ (* \sim a,$ $a \in A).$ Our instructor says that it is $X/A.$ But how do I see that? Would anybody please give me some suggestion regarding that?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your equivalence relation says that $* \sim a$ for every $a \in A$. Hence, all of $A$ is collapsed into the point $*$.

Other way of seeing it would be through the universal property of pushout, which in this case is equivalent to the universal property of quotients in the category of topological spaces.

Comment: By the universal property of pushout the resultant space will be homeomorphic to $(X \coprod_f *),$ where $(X \coprod_f *) : = (X \coprod *)/ \sim$ where the equivalence relation $\sim$ is given as follows $:$ $$x \sim * \iff x \in A.$$

Comment: I think the pushout will be homeomorphic to the pointed space $(X/A,*).$